# TYPO3 Extension - Object Storage NULL

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

I'm programming a typo3 extension for products and consumables (1:n relation). For example a car (product) and fuel, oil and so on (materials).
It's just an example, so fuel is not necessary for other cars in my case ;)

So I created it near by the simpleblog example from Patrik Lohbacher. In this case you can say product=blog and material=post.

So my problem ist in the show view of the product. I want to see the materials of this product, but it's not working. In f:debug for {product} I can see all the materials correctly and also in Backend everything seems to be fine.

[fdebug view of product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64ZCB.jpg)

But when I try to see {product.materials} in fdebug there is a NULL.

What did I forget? What could be the problem?

```
    MyEXTENSION\MyExtension\Domain\Model\Produktprototypepersistent entity (uid=1, pid=39)
       crdate => '1494240491' (10 chars)
       crfromid => '2' (1 chars)
       crfromusername => 'hans' (4 chars)
       crfromfirstname => 'Hans' (4 chars)
       crfromlastname => 'Hanssen' (7 chars)
       updatefromid => '0' (1 chars)
       updatefromusername => '' (0 chars)
       updatefromfirstname => '' (0 chars)
       updatefromlastname => '' (0 chars)
       tstamp => '1494240524' (10 chars)
       bezeichnung => 'test1' (5 chars)
       hersteller => 'hersteller1' (11 chars)
       warengruppe => 'wg1' (3 chars)
       tnutzungsdauer => 0 (integer)
       preis => 0 (double)
       miete => 0 (double)
       abschreibungsart => 'linear' (6 chars)
       abschreibungsdauer => 0 (integer)
       geraeteentsorgung => 0 (double)
       sonstigekosten => 0 (double)
       montage => 0 (double)
       itanbindung => 0 (double)
       geraeteabnahme => 0 (double)
       mageraeteeinweisung => 0 (double)
       gewaehrleistungsfrist => 0 (integer)
       softwareupdates => 0 (double)
       softwareupdateturnus => 'nicht gefordert' (15 chars)
       stkturnus => 'nicht gefordert' (15 chars)
       stkprodurchfuehrung => 0 (double)
       mtkturnus => 'nicht gefordert' (15 chars)
       mtkprodurchfuehrung => 0 (double)
       dguvv3turnus => 'nicht gefordert' (15 chars)
       dguvv3produrchfuehrung => 0 (double)
       konstanzpruefungturnus => 'monatlich' (9 chars)
       konstanzpruefungprodurchfuehrung => 0 (double)
       messpruefungturnus => 'monatlich' (9 chars)
       messpruefungprodurchfuehrung => 0 (double)
       jaehrlichepreisanpassung => 0 (integer)
       materials => TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorageprototypeobject (1 items)
       uid => 1 (integer)
       _localizedUid => 1 (integer)modified
       _languageUid => 0 (integer)modified
       _versionedUid => 1 (integer)modified
       pid => 39 (integer)
```

and yes, I know that it should be 'product' instead of 'produkt' ;)

```
    /**
     * Returns the materials
     * 
     * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\MyEXTENSION\MyExtension\Domain\Model\Material> $materials
     */
    public function getMaterials()
    {
      return $this->materials();
    }
```

```
/**
 * Sets the materials
 * 
 * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\MyEXTENSION\MyExtension\Domain\Model\Material> $materials
 * @return void
 */
public function setMaterials(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage $materials)
{
  $this->materials = $materials;
}
```

Produkt.php

```
namespace MyEXTENSION\MyExtension\Domain\Model;
```

/***************************************************************
 *
 *  Copyright notice
 *
 *  (c) 2017 Sebastian Christoph , HELIOS IT
 *
 *  All rights reserved
 *
 *  This script is part of the TYPO3 project. The TYPO3 project is
 *  free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 *  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 *  the Free Software Foundation; either version 3 of the License, or
 *  (at your option) any later version.
 *
 *  The GNU General Public License can be found at
 *  http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html.
 *
 *  This script is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 *  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 *  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 *  GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 *  This copyright notice MUST APPEAR in all copies of the script!
 ***************************************************************/

/**
 * Produkt
 */
class Produkt extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity
{

```
/**
 * crdate
 * 
 * @var string
 */
 protected $crdate;  

 /**
  * crfromid
  * 
  * @var string
  */
 protected $crfromid;

 /**
  * crfromusername
  * 
  * @var string
  */
 protected $crfromusername;

 /**
  * crfromfirstname
  * 
  * @var string
  */
 protected $crfromfirstname;     

 /**
  * crfromlastname
  * 
  * @var string
  */
 protected $crfromlastname;     

 /**
  * updatefromid
  * 
  * @var string
  */
 protected $updatefromid;

 /**
  * updatefromusername
  * 
  * @var string
  */
 protected $updatefromusername;

 /**
  * updatefromfirstname
  * 
  * @var string
  */
 protected $updatefromfirstname;

 /**
  * updatefromlastname
  * 
  * @var string
  */
 protected $updatefromlastname;     

/**
 * tstamp
 * 
 * @var string
 */
 protected $tstamp;    

/**
 * bezeichnung
 *
 * @var string
 * @validate NotEmpty
 */
protected $bezeichnung = '';

/**
 * hersteller
 *
 * @var string
 * @validate NotEmpty
 */
protected $hersteller = '';

/**
 * warengruppe
 *
 * @var string
 * @validate NotEmpty
 */
protected $warengruppe = '';

/**
 * tnutzungsdauer
 *
 * @var int
 */
protected $tnutzungsdauer = 0;

/**
 * preis
 *
 * @var float
 */
protected $preis = 0.0;

/**
 * miete
 *
 * @var float
 */
protected $miete = 0.0;

/**
 * abschreibungsart
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $abschreibungsart = '';

/**
 * abschreibungsdauer
 *
 * @var int
 */
protected $abschreibungsdauer = 0;

/**
 * geraeteentsorgung
 *
 * @var float
 */
protected $geraeteentsorgung = 0.0;

/**
 * sonstigekosten
 *
 * @var float
 */
protected $sonstigekosten = 0.0;

/**
 * montage
 *
 * @var float
 */
protected $montage = 0.0;

/**
 * itanbindung
 *
 * @var float
 */
protected $itanbindung = 0.0;

/**
 * geraeteabnahme
 *
 * @var float
 */
protected $geraeteabnahme = 0.0;

/**
 * mageraeteeinweisung
 *
 * @var float
 */
protected $mageraeteeinweisung = 0.0;

/**
 * gewaehrleistungsfrist
 *
 * @var int
 */
protected $gewaehrleistungsfrist = 0;

/**
 * softwareupdates
 *
 * @var float
 */
protected $softwareupdates = 0.0;

/**
 * softwareupdateturnus
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $softwareupdateturnus = '';

/**
 * stkturnus
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $stkturnus = '';

/**
 * stkprodurchfuehrung
 *
 * @var float
 */
protected $stkprodurchfuehrung = 0.0;

/**
 * mtkturnus
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $mtkturnus = '';

/**
 * mtkprodurchfuehrung
 *
 * @var float
 */
protected $mtkprodurchfuehrung = 0.0;

/**
 * dguvv3turnus
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $dguvv3turnus = '';

/**
 * dguvv3produrchfuehrung
 *
 * @var float
 */
protected $dguvv3produrchfuehrung = 0.0;

/**
 * konstanzpruefungturnus
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $konstanzpruefungturnus = '';

/**
 * konstanzpruefungprodurchfuehrung
 *
 * @var float
 */
protected $konstanzpruefungprodurchfuehrung = 0.0;

/**
 * messpruefungturnus
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $messpruefungturnus = '';

/**
 * messpruefungprodurchfuehrung
 *
 * @var float
 */
protected $messpruefungprodurchfuehrung = 0.0;

/**
 * jaehrlichepreisanpassung
 *
 * @var int
 */
protected $jaehrlichepreisanpassung = 0;

/**
 * Produkt Material
 * 
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\MyEXTENSION\MyExtension\Domain\Model\Material>
 */
protected $materials = null;

/**
 * __construct
 */
public function __construct() 
{
  $this->initStorageObjects();
}

/**
 * Initializes all ObjectStorage properties
 * 
 * @return void
 */
protected function initStorageObjects()
{
  $this->materials = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage();
}

/**
 * Returns the crdate
 * 
 * @return string $crdate
 */
public function getCrdate() {
  return $this->crdate;
}

/**
 * Sets the crdate
 * 
 * @param string $crdate
 * @return void
 */
public function setCrdate($crdate) {
  $this->crdate = $crdate;
}

/**
 * Returns the crfromid
 * 
 * @return string $crfromid
 */
public function getCrfromid() {
  return $this->crfromid;
}

/**
 * Sets the crfromid
 * 
 * @param string $crfromid
 * @return void
 */
public function setCrfromid($crfromid) {
  $this->crfromid = $crfromid;
}
```

/**
     * Returns the crfromusername
     * 
     * @return string $crfromusername
     */
    public function getCrfromusername() {
      return $this->crfromusername;
    }

```
/**
 * Sets the crfromusername
 * 
 * @param string $crfromusername
 * @return void
 */
public function setCrfromusername($crfromusername) {
  $this->crfromusername = $crfromusername;
}
```

/**
     * Returns the crfromlastname
     * 
     * @return string $crfromlastname
     */
    public function getCrfromlastname() {
      return $this->crfromlastname;
    }

```
/**
 * Sets the crfromlastname
 * 
 * @param string $crfromlastname
 * @return void
 */
public function setCrfromlastname($crfromlastname) {
  $this->crfromlastname = $crfromlastname;
}
```

/**
     * Returns the crfromfirstname
     * 
     * @return string $crfromfirstname
     */
    public function getCrfromfirstname() {
      return $this->crfromfirstname;
    }

```
/**
 * Sets the crfromfirstname
 * 
 * @param string $crfromfirstname
 * @return void
 */
public function setCrfromfirstname($crfromfirstname) {
  $this->crfromfirstname = $crfromfirstname;
}    

/**
 * Returns the updatefromid
 * 
 * @return string $updatefromid
 */
public function getUpdatefromid() {
  return $this->updatefromid;
}

/**
 * Sets the updatefromid
 * 
 * @param string $updatefromid
 * @return void
 */
public function setUpdatefromid($updatefromid) {
  $this->updatefromid = $updatefromid;
}

/**
 * Returns the updatefromusername
 * 
 * @return string $updatefromusername
 */
public function getUpdatefromusername() {
  return $this->updatefromusername;
}

/**
 * Sets the updatefromusername
 * 
 * @param string $updatefromusername
 * @return void
 */
public function setUpdatefromusername($updatefromusername) {
  $this->updatefromusername = $updatefromusername;
}   

/**
 * Returns the updatefromlastname
 * 
 * @return string $updatefromlastname
 */
public function getUpdatefromlastname() {
  return $this->updatefromlastname;
}

/**
 * Sets the updatefromlastname
 * 
 * @param string $updatefromlastname
 * @return void
 */
public function setUpdatefromlastname($updatefromlastname) {
  $this->updatefromlastname = $updatefromlastname;
}   

/**
 * Returns the updatefromfirstname
 * 
 * @return string $updatefromfirstname
 */
public function getUpdatefromfirstname() {
  return $this->updatefromfirstname;
}

/**
 * Sets the updatefromfirstname
 * 
 * @param string $updatefromfirstname
 * @return void
 */
public function setUpdatefromfirstname($updatefromfirstname) {
  $this->updatefromfirstname = $updatefromfirstname;
}    

/**
 * Returns the tstamp
 * 
 * @return string tstamp
 */
public function getTstamp() {
  return $this->tstamp;
}

/**
 * Sets the tstamp
 * 
 * @param string tstamp
 * @return void
 */
public function setTstamp($tstamp) {
  $this->tstamp = $tstamp;
}    

/**
 * Returns the bezeichnung
 *
 * @return string bezeichnung
 */
public function getBezeichnung()
{
    return $this->bezeichnung;
}

/**
 * Sets the bezeichnung
 *
 * @param string $bezeichnung
 * @return void
 */
public function setBezeichnung($bezeichnung)
{
    $this->bezeichnung = $bezeichnung;
}

/**
 * Returns the hersteller
 *
 * @return string $hersteller
 */
public function getHersteller()
{
    return $this->hersteller;
}

/**
 * Sets the hersteller
 *
 * @param string $hersteller
 * @return void
 */
public function setHersteller($hersteller)
{
    $this->hersteller = $hersteller;
}

/**
 * Returns the warengruppe
 *
 * @return string $warengruppe
 */
public function getWarengruppe()
{
    return $this->warengruppe;
}

/**
 * Sets the warengruppe
 *
 * @param string $warengruppe
 * @return void
 */
public function setWarengruppe($warengruppe)
{
    $this->warengruppe = $warengruppe;
}

/**
 * Returns the tnutzungsdauer
 *
 * @return int $tnutzungsdauer
 */
public function getTnutzungsdauer()
{
    return $this->tnutzungsdauer;
}

/**
 * Sets the tnutzungsdauer
 *
 * @param int $tnutzungsdauer
 * @return void
 */
public function setTnutzungsdauer($tnutzungsdauer)
{
    $this->tnutzungsdauer = $tnutzungsdauer;
}

/**
 * Returns the preis
 *
 * @return float $preis
 */
public function getPreis()
{
    return $this->preis;
}

/**
 * Sets the preis
 *
 * @param float $preis
 * @return void
 */
public function setPreis($preis)
{
    $this->preis = $preis;
}

/**
 * Returns the miete
 *
 * @return float $miete
 */
public function getMiete()
{
    return $this->miete;
}

/**
 * Sets the miete
 *
 * @param float $miete
 * @return void
 */
public function setMiete($miete)
{
    $this->miete = $miete;
}

/**
 * Returns the abschreibungsart
 *
 * @return string $abschreibungsart
 */
public function getAbschreibungsart()
{
    return $this->abschreibungsart;
}

/**
 * Sets the abschreibungsart
 *
 * @param string $abschreibungsart
 * @return void
 */
public function setAbschreibungsart($abschreibungsart)
{
    $this->abschreibungsart = $abschreibungsart;
}

/**
 * Returns the abschreibungsdauer
 *
 * @return int $abschreibungsdauer
 */
public function getAbschreibungsdauer()
{
    return $this->abschreibungsdauer;
}

/**
 * Sets the abschreibungsdauer
 *
 * @param int $abschreibungsdauer
 * @return void
 */
public function setAbschreibungsdauer($abschreibungsdauer)
{
    $this->abschreibungsdauer = $abschreibungsdauer;
}

/**
 * Returns the geraeteentsorgung
 *
 * @return float $geraeteentsorgung
 */
public function getGeraeteentsorgung()
{
    return $this->geraeteentsorgung;
}

/**
 * Sets the geraeteentsorgung
 *
 * @param float $geraeteentsorgung
 * @return void
 */
public function setGeraeteentsorgung($geraeteentsorgung)
{
    $this->geraeteentsorgung = $geraeteentsorgung;
}

/**
 * Returns the sonstigekosten
 *
 * @return float $sonstigekosten
 */
public function getSonstigekosten()
{
    return $this->sonstigekosten;
}

/**
 * Sets the sonstigekosten
 *
 * @param float $sonstigekosten
 * @return void
 */
public function setSonstigekosten($sonstigekosten)
{
    $this->sonstigekosten = $sonstigekosten;
}

/**
 * Returns the montage
 *
 * @return float $montage
 */
public function getMontage()
{
    return $this->montage;
}

/**
 * Sets the montage
 *
 * @param float $montage
 * @return void
 */
public function setMontage($montage)
{
    $this->montage = $montage;
}

/**
 * Returns the itanbindung
 *
 * @return float $itanbindung
 */
public function getItanbindung()
{
    return $this->itanbindung;
}

/**
 * Sets the itanbindung
 *
 * @param float $itanbindung
 * @return void
 */
public function setItanbindung($itanbindung)
{
    $this->itanbindung = $itanbindung;
}

/**
 * Returns the geraeteabnahme
 *
 * @return float $geraeteabnahme
 */
public function getGeraeteabnahme()
{
    return $this->geraeteabnahme;
}

/**
 * Sets the geraeteabnahme
 *
 * @param float $geraeteabnahme
 * @return void
 */
public function setGeraeteabnahme($geraeteabnahme)
{
    $this->geraeteabnahme = $geraeteabnahme;
}

/**
 * Returns the mageraeteeinweisung
 *
 * @return float $mageraeteeinweisung
 */
public function getMageraeteeinweisung()
{
    return $this->mageraeteeinweisung;
}

/**
 * Sets the mageraeteeinweisung
 *
 * @param float $mageraeteeinweisung
 * @return void
 */
public function setMageraeteeinweisung($mageraeteeinweisung)
{
    $this->mageraeteeinweisung = $mageraeteeinweisung;
}

/**
 * Returns the gewaehrleistungsfrist
 *
 * @return int $gewaehrleistungsfrist
 */
public function getGewaehrleistungsfrist()
{
    return $this->gewaehrleistungsfrist;
}

/**
 * Sets the gewaehrleistungsfrist
 *
 * @param int $gewaehrleistungsfrist
 * @return void
 */
public function setGewaehrleistungsfrist($gewaehrleistungsfrist)
{
    $this->gewaehrleistungsfrist = $gewaehrleistungsfrist;
}

/**
 * Returns the softwareupdates
 *
 * @return float $softwareupdates
 */
public function getSoftwareupdates()
{
    return $this->softwareupdates;
}

/**
 * Sets the softwareupdates
 *
 * @param float $softwareupdates
 * @return void
 */
public function setSoftwareupdates($softwareupdates)
{
    $this->softwareupdates = $softwareupdates;
}

/**
 * Returns the softwareupdateturnus
 *
 * @return string $softwareupdateturnus
 */
public function getSoftwareupdateturnus()
{
    return $this->softwareupdateturnus;
}

/**
 * Sets the softwareupdateturnus
 *
 * @param string $softwareupdateturnus
 * @return void
 */
public function setSoftwareupdateturnus($softwareupdateturnus)
{
    $this->softwareupdateturnus = $softwareupdateturnus;
}

/**
 * Returns the stkturnus
 *
 * @return string $stkturnus
 */
public function getStkturnus()
{
    return $this->stkturnus;
}

/**
 * Sets the stkturnus
 *
 * @param string $stkturnus
 * @return void
 */
public function setStkturnus($stkturnus)
{
    $this->stkturnus = $stkturnus;
}

/**
 * Returns the stkprodurchfuehrung
 *
 * @return float $stkprodurchfuehrung
 */
public function getStkprodurchfuehrung()
{
    return $this->stkprodurchfuehrung;
}

/**
 * Sets the stkprodurchfuehrung
 *
 * @param float $stkprodurchfuehrung
 * @return void
 */
public function setStkprodurchfuehrung($stkprodurchfuehrung)
{
    $this->stkprodurchfuehrung = $stkprodurchfuehrung;
}

/**
 * Returns the mtkturnus
 *
 * @return string $mtkturnus
 */
public function getMtkturnus()
{
    return $this->mtkturnus;
}

/**
 * Sets the mtkturnus
 *
 * @param string $mtkturnus
 * @return void
 */
public function setMtkturnus($mtkturnus)
{
    $this->mtkturnus = $mtkturnus;
}

/**
 * Returns the mtkprodurchfuehrung
 *
 * @return float $mtkprodurchfuehrung
 */
public function getMtkprodurchfuehrung()
{
    return $this->mtkprodurchfuehrung;
}

/**
 * Sets the mtkprodurchfuehrung
 *
 * @param float $mtkprodurchfuehrung
 * @return void
 */
public function setMtkprodurchfuehrung($mtkprodurchfuehrung)
{
    $this->mtkprodurchfuehrung = $mtkprodurchfuehrung;
}

/**
 * Returns the dguvv3turnus
 *
 * @return string $dguvv3turnus
 */
public function getDguvv3turnus()
{
    return $this->dguvv3turnus;
}

/**
 * Sets the dguvv3turnus
 *
 * @param string $dguvv3turnus
 * @return void
 */
public function setDguvv3turnus($dguvv3turnus)
{
    $this->dguvv3turnus = $dguvv3turnus;
}

/**
 * Returns the dguvv3produrchfuehrung
 *
 * @return float $dguvv3produrchfuehrung
 */
public function getDguvv3produrchfuehrung()
{
    return $this->dguvv3produrchfuehrung;
}

/**
 * Sets the dguvv3produrchfuehrung
 *
 * @param float $dguvv3produrchfuehrung
 * @return void
 */
public function setDguvv3produrchfuehrung($dguvv3produrchfuehrung)
{
    $this->dguvv3produrchfuehrung = $dguvv3produrchfuehrung;
}

/**
 * Returns the konstanzpruefungturnus
 *
 * @return string $konstanzpruefungturnus
 */
public function getKonstanzpruefungturnus()
{
    return $this->konstanzpruefungturnus;
}

/**
 * Sets the konstanzpruefungturnus
 *
 * @param string $konstanzpruefungturnus
 * @return void
 */
public function setKonstanzpruefungturnus($konstanzpruefungturnus)
{
    $this->konstanzpruefungturnus = $konstanzpruefungturnus;
}

/**
 * Returns the konstanzpruefungprodurchfuehrung
 *
 * @return float $konstanzpruefungprodurchfuehrung
 */
public function getKonstanzpruefungprodurchfuehrung()
{
    return $this->konstanzpruefungprodurchfuehrung;
}

/**
 * Sets the konstanzpruefungprodurchfuehrung
 *
 * @param float $konstanzpruefungprodurchfuehrung
 * @return void
 */
public function setKonstanzpruefungprodurchfuehrung($konstanzpruefungprodurchfuehrung)
{
    $this->konstanzpruefungprodurchfuehrung = $konstanzpruefungprodurchfuehrung;
}

/**
 * Returns the messpruefungturnus
 *
 * @return string $messpruefungturnus
 */
public function getMesspruefungturnus()
{
    return $this->messpruefungturnus;
}

/**
 * Sets the messpruefungturnus
 *
 * @param string $messpruefungturnus
 * @return void
 */
public function setMesspruefungturnus($messpruefungturnus)
{
    $this->messpruefungturnus = $messpruefungturnus;
}

/**
 * Returns the messpruefungprodurchfuehrung
 *
 * @return float $messpruefungprodurchfuehrung
 */
public function getMesspruefungprodurchfuehrung()
{
    return $this->messpruefungprodurchfuehrung;
}

/**
 * Sets the messpruefungprodurchfuehrung
 *
 * @param float $messpruefungprodurchfuehrung
 * @return void
 */
public function setMesspruefungprodurchfuehrung($messpruefungprodurchfuehrung)
{
    $this->messpruefungprodurchfuehrung = $messpruefungprodurchfuehrung;
}

/**
 * Returns the jaehrlichepreisanpassung
 *
 * @return int $jaehrlichepreisanpassung
 */
public function getJaehrlichepreisanpassung()
{
    return $this->jaehrlichepreisanpassung;
}

/**
 * Sets the jaehrlichepreisanpassung
 *
 * @param int $jaehrlichepreisanpassung
 * @return void
 */
public function setJaehrlichepreisanpassung($jaehrlichepreisanpassung)
{
    $this->jaehrlichepreisanpassung = $jaehrlichepreisanpassung;
}

/**
 * Adds a Material
 * 
 * @param \MyEXTENSION\MyExtension\Domain\Model\Material $material
 * @return void
 */
public function addMaterial(\MyEXTENSION\MyExtension\Domain\Model\Material $material)
{
  $this->materials->attach($material);
}

/**
 * Removes a material
 * 
 * @param \MyEXTENSION\MyExtension\Domain\Model\Material $materialToRemove
 * The Material to be removed
 * @return void
 */
public function removeMaterial(\MyEXTENSION\MyExtension\Domain\Model\Material $materialToRemove)
{
  $this->materials->detach($materialToRemove);
}

/**
 * Returns the materials
 * 
 * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\MyEXTENSION\MyExtension\Domain\Model\Material> $materials
 */
public function getMaterials()
{
  return $this->materials();
}

/**
 * Sets the materials
 * 
 * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\MyEXTENSION\MyExtension\Domain\Model\Material> $materials
 * @return void
 */
public function setMaterials(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage $materials)
{
  $this->materials = $materials;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Updated to reflect state of discussion)

Line 1138 should read:

`return $this->materials;`

Comment: I removed the @lazy notation and cleared all caches, but nothing changed.

Comment: Have you verified that there is indeed a method getMaterials() in your Material model?

Comment: ok that was missing ! but you mean in product model or am I wrong?
If I'm adding getMaterials and setMaterials (see code in question) then I got

Call to undefined method MyEXTENSION\MyExtension\Domain\Model\Produkt::materials()

Error thrown in file
/var/www/html/typo3conf/ext/myextension/Classes/Domain/Model/Produkt.php in line 1138.

Comment: Yes, in Produkt.php, sorry. The Fluid interpreter will try to call a method called getX() whenever you use {object.x}. Did you kickstart your extension using the Extension Builder extension? It will automatically generate all necessary Setters and Getters for you. Could you post the complete file (especially to see what line 1138 says). Maybe use a gist or similar if possible?

Comment: Line 1138 is the return statement od the getMaterials function. I will add it in the question.
In the beginning of the extension I used the Extension Builder (Typo Version 7.6.18) but now I removed all the trash files for that to learn more about extension programming, so this is my learning now ;)

Comment: Oh YES... that was it. Thank you very much... drove crazy because of that ^^